# Read Image File Through Java Socket

Tags: java, http, sockets, http-headers

This is what I have so far,

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);

ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] byteChunk = new byte[1024];

int c = is.read(byteChunk);

while (c != -1){
    buffer.write(byteChunk, 0, c);
    c = is.read(byteChunk);
}

BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray()));
```

My problem with my code is `ImageIO.read()` returns null.

When I print the content of `ByteArrayOutputStream` object what i get is header part

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 30 Dec 2011 11:34:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) ...........
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Dec 2011 19:12:23 GMT
ETag: "502812-490e-4b48ad8d273c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 18702
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

followed with a empty line plus many lines with different characters such as `Àã$sU,e6‡Í~áŸP;Öã…`.

Again my problem is `ImageIO.read()` function returns null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you seem to be querying from HTTP, why not use an HTTP client implementation instead of a raw socket?

Comment: I need to use sockets for practice.

Comment: print the image bytes and compare them before-write and after-read. if it matches then there is no problem in transmission. then we look in other aspects.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage, java.lang.String, java.io.OutputStream) to write the image into the socket. Note that you need to specify the image format when you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't want to use simple http URL to get image from host?
I mean:

```
URL imageURL = new URL("http://host:port/address");
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
```

If you want to use plain socket you have to parse http response and extract data from the http reply manually: read/skip headers, read binary data and pass it to `ImageIO.read` (or seek stream to correct position and pass stream to `ImageIO.read`).

Comment: I am restricted to use plain sockets. Do you mean I need to get rid of HTTP Header parts that i mention in my question ?

Comment: @nevayeshirazi yep, of course you need to get plain image binary data to pass it to ImageIO.read method.

Comment: -1 for no answer & "a lot of code" - 1/skip header 2/get body 3/save (if u are not sure of stream origin/type u can always check headers/content-type)