# Read Image from Socket

Tags: java, image, sockets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read Image File Through Java Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679112/read-image-file-through-java-socket)

```
void readImage() throws IOException
{
    socket = new Socket("upload.wikimedia.org", 80);


    DataOutputStream bw = new DataOutputStream(new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
    bw.writeBytes("GET /wikipedia/commons/8/80/Knut_IMG_8095.jpg HTTP/1.1\n");
    bw.writeBytes("Host: wlab.cs.bilkent.edu.tr:80\n\n");

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    File file = new File("imgg.jpg");
    file.createNewFile();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    int count;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
      dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
      dos.flush();
    }
    dos.close();
    System.out.println("image transfer done");

    socket.close();     
}
```

-Create a socket
-Create output stream
-Request the page that includes image
-Read socket to an input stream
-Write to file

I am trying to read an image from socket.
But it is not working.

It seems to read and the image is opened but can not be seen

Where is the problem?

Comment: why you dont use a RTP class for that?

Comment: What is not working? Any exception? What's the stack trace? Are you aware that Java supporst HTTP natively? Look at URLConnection.

Comment: This is the second 'read image from socket' question this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to skip HTTP headers to get correct image.

I've already answered to this question today, look at: [Read Image File Through Java Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679112/read-image-file-through-java-socket/8679160#8679160)

The second problem, that you are trying to receive an image from wikipedia without referer and wikipedia restrict to do that (you receiving access denied every time). Try to use another image URL (google image for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL objects directly to fetch HTTP content. The input stream returned by the URL object will only contain content at the URL. The example method below takes a URL, fetches its content and writes the content to a given file.

```
public static void createImageFile(URL url, File file) throws IOException{
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    byte[] b = new byte[1024]; // 1 kB read blocks.
    URLConnection conn;

    try{
        conn = url.openConnection();

        /* Set some connection options here 
           before opening the stream 
           (i.e. connect and read timeouts) */

        is = conn.getInputStream();


        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int i = 0;
        do{
            i = is.read(b);
            if(i != -1)
                fos.write(b, 0, i);
        }while(i != -1)
    }finally{
    /* Don't forget to clean up. */
        if(is != null){
            try{
                is.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                /* Don't care */
            }
        }
        if(fos != null){
            try{
                fos.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
               /* Don't care */
            }
        }
    }

}
```